# Не выводится скалярное произведение каждой строки

Tags: java, массивы

подскажите, что не так, если присваиваю скалярное произведение каждой строки одномерному массиву, то вывод только два элемента, а остальное 0?

> Создать программу, которая вводит c клавиатуры два двумерных массива целых чисел a и b, заносит в два других одномерных массива c и d скалярные произведения строк массива a и столбцов массива b, выводит на экран массивы c и d и находит минимум из сумм ненулевых элементов двух этих массивов.

```
package com.example.mas;

public class arr3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = {{4, -3, 1},
                {5, -2, -3},
                {7, 8, 9}};
        int [] a1 = new int [a.length];
        int [] b1 = new int [a.length];
        int p = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
                {
                    p = p + a[i][k] * a[j][k];
                    a1[i] = p;
                }
                //System.out.println(a1[i]);
                p = 0;
            }
        }
        int p1 = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            for(int i = j+1; i < a.length; i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
                {
                    p1 = p1 + a[j][k] * a[i][k];
                    b1[j] = p1;
                }
                System.out.println(b1[j]);
                p1 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите тестовые данные, которые вы вводите и что получаете на выходе. Вопрос не совсем понятен.