# Почему не выводится скалярное произведение строк матрицы в виде одномерного массива

Tags: java, массивы

Создать программу, которая вводит c клавиатуры два двумерных массива целых чисел a и b, заносит в два других одномерных массива c и d скалярные произведения строк массива a и столбцов массива b, выводит на экран массивы c и d и находит минимум из сумм ненулевых элементов двух этих массивов.
package com.example.mas;

```
   public class arr3 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {{4, -3, 1},
            {5, -2, -3},
            {7, 8, 9}};
      int [] a1 = new int [a.length];
      int [] b1 = new int [a.length];
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
       {
        for(int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
            {
                p = p + a[i][k] * a[j][k];
                a1[i] = p;
            }
            //System.out.println(a1[i]);
            p = 0;
        }
      }
       int p1 = 0;
      for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
    {
        for(int i = j+1; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
            {
                p1 = p1 + a[j][k] * a[i][k];
                b1[j] = p1;
            }
            System.out.println(b1[j]);
            p1 = 0;
        }
    }

}}
```

Comment: А разве это не тот же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/703579/186083 вопрос?

Comment: Валентина, у нас не принято задавать один и тот же вопрос, пожалуйста, не спамьте своими вопросами. На следующий раз возможно придётся объясняться с модераторами.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это дубликат ранее заданного пользователем вопроса.